# What's the best way to manage SQLite connections in Windows from a .NET application?

Tags: .net, windows, sqlite

I'm using SQLite in Windows from a .NET app.  The .NET app is using the [Open Source System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) library.

In my app, there are many threads accessing the same database.  Is it best to:

1. Create and destroy connections as needed *(what's the maximum number I can have?)*
2. Create a long lived connection and use it from different threads *(is this safe?)*
3. Something else?

I initially went with choice# 2 but got random/intermittent errors relating to transactions when accessing the connection from other threads.  I've since moved to choice# 1 and there error has gone.

Comment: FYI, the link seems to be broken...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6), the latest version of SQLite does allow multiple threads to use the same connection, but only one of them can have a transaction at a time.

I'm not aware of any built-in limit on the number of connections that may be active at a time.

I recommend setting up a "database thread" that owns the connection, and performs tasks on behalf of the other threads. This is what I'm doing in my .NET 4 SQLite process, and it works quite well.

P.S. If you're interested, I recently wrote a blog post about [using SQLite via Entity Framework 4](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/06/sqlite-and-entity-framework-4.html).